# How to use pipe to apply a text to a program

Tags: bash, command-line, pipe, io-redirection

My instructor says to use a pipe to apply a text file, which consists a list of test cases, to a working program that takes test case from the input file.
Say i have

```
test_cases.txt
my_program //my java program after compliation
```

and when I did this

```
java my_program | test_cases.txt
```

it gives

```
[1]+ Stopped               java my_program | test_cases.txt
```

Not sure how to use pipe...

Comment: "apply a text file" is a meaningless phrase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, a pipe connects two **processes**, not files (including text files), such that the output of one goes to the input of the other. The presumption is that the process "generating" the output sends it to `STDOUT`, which becomes the source for the pipe, and that the process "receiving" the input reads it from `STDIN`, which becomes the destination of the pipe. You cannot connect a pipe to a text file, or any other file, only to processes.

Second, when using a pipe the process on the left side of the pipe is the one that uses `STDOUT`, and the process on the right side of the pipe uses `STDIN`. Therefore, your attempted command would be trying to send the *output* of `my_program` to the pipe, not reading from it.

If you properly presented the instructions you were given, then it can't work anyway. The instructions ends with "... a working program takes test cases from the input file." If the program takes input from a file, then it *is not* reading from `STDIN`, and would ignore the data from the pipe anyway.

To make it work with a pipe, `my_program` has to be written to read from the `STDIN`, as in expecting you to type the test cases by hand at a prompt. Then you could rewrite the command line as

`cat text_cases.txt | jave my_program`

`cat` is a **process** that will read the text file and send its contents to `STDOUT`, then `my_program` would "read" the data from `STDIN` using the pipe instead of you typing it manually. Since I don't know how java connects with pipes, this is based on the presumption that it will behave in a standard way, since the instructor asked you to use that method.

IMHO it would be better, as in less resource usage, to use redirection than a pipe.

`java my_program < test_cases.txt`

That is, unless this is one step that will be included in a larger chain of processes later in the course where using a pipe will become necessary.